# Quick test code option in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to execute code quick test in VS2010?

For example I would like to test code below just selecting it in code editor and execute it by passing variables?

```
 public static int GetInt(object value)
    {
        int result;
        Int32.TryParse(GetString(value), out result);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83hd8f1e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as a starting point on how to use the immediate window. This will allow you to test the entire GetInt method.